How to force an immediate call to idle handler
I'm not much of an Applescript programmer, but am trying to learn.  Currently, I'm playing with the idle handler.
Scavenging the web, I've managed to write a stay-open script with a handler that is called every 20 seconds. (note: it has no error handling for brevity) It has a menu bar item that allows the handler calling frequency to be changed.
The code works great, but the change in handler calling frequency is not immediately utilized.  Only when the idle handler is called does the new frequency take effect.
Ideally, I would like to force an immediate call to the handler and have the new frequency immediately utilized.  Is this possible?
--******************* Begin Timer Code *******************
global sleepTimeSeconds
set sleepTimeSeconds to 20

on idle
    say "Hi!!  I'm awake now."
    
    return sleepTimeSeconds
end idle
--******************** End Timer Code ********************

--****************** Begin MenuBar Code ******************
use AppleScript version "2.4"
use scripting additions
use framework "Foundation"
use framework "AppKit"

-- init new menu bar to build menus from scratch
set menubar to current application's NSMenu's alloc()'s init()

-- clear predefined menus
set menuBarItem to current application's NSMenuItem's new()
menubar's addItem:menuBarItem
current application's NSApp's setMainMenu:menubar
current application's NSApp's mainMenu()'s removeAllItems()

-- make and edit App name's menu 
set asstMenuItem to menubar's addItemWithTitle:"" action:(missing value) keyEquivalent:""
set asstMenu to current application's NSMenu's alloc()'s init()
menubar's setSubmenu:asstMenu forItem:asstMenuItem
set quitMenuItem to asstMenu's addItemWithTitle:"Quit" action:"actionHandler:" keyEquivalent:"q"
(quitMenuItem's setTarget:me)

-- make and edit "File" menu 
set asstMenuItem to menubar's addItemWithTitle:"" action:(missing value) keyEquivalent:""
set asstMenu to current application's NSMenu's alloc()'s initWithTitle:"File"
menubar's setSubmenu:asstMenu forItem:asstMenuItem
set openMenuItem to asstMenu's addItemWithTitle:"Show Sleep Time Seconds" action:"actionHandler:" keyEquivalent:"t"
(openMenuItem's setTarget:me)

-- make and edit "Edit" menu
set asstMenuItem to menubar's addItemWithTitle:"" action:(missing value) keyEquivalent:""
set asstMenu to current application's NSMenu's alloc()'s initWithTitle:"Edit"
menubar's setSubmenu:asstMenu forItem:asstMenuItem
set openMenuItem to asstMenu's addItemWithTitle:"Edit Sleep Time Seconds" action:"actionHandler:" keyEquivalent:"e"
(openMenuItem's setTarget:me)

on actionHandler:sender
    set theMenuItemTitle to title of sender as string
    if theMenuItemTitle is "Quit" then quit
    if theMenuItemTitle is "Show Sleep Time Seconds" then
        showSleepTimeSeconds(theMenuItemTitle)
    end if
    if theMenuItemTitle is "Edit Sleep Time Seconds" then
        editSleepTimeSeconds(theMenuItemTitle)
    end if
end actionHandler:

on showSleepTimeSeconds(theMenuItemTitle)
    display alert "Sleep Time = " & (sleepTimeSeconds as string) & " seconds." giving up after 3
end showSleepTimeSeconds

on editSleepTimeSeconds(theMenuItemTitle)
    try
        set theResultReturned to (display dialog "Provide new Sleep Time in seconds:" default answer (sleepTimeSeconds as string) buttons {"Save", "Cancel"} default button "Cancel")
    on error
        showSleepTimeSeconds(theMenuItemTitle)
        return
    end try
    
    set theTextReturned to the text returned of theResultReturned
    set theButtonReturned to the button returned of theResultReturned
    if theButtonReturned = "Save" then
        set sleepTimeSeconds to theTextReturned as number
    end if
    showSleepTimeSeconds(theMenuItemTitle)
end editSleepTimeSeconds
--******************* End MenuBar Code *******************


The regular AppleScript idle handler is essentially a wrapper for a one-shot NSTimer that is reset with the value returned by the handler.  If this is going to be something like a countdown timer, you might take a look at creating your own repeating timer that fires, say, once a second, and in the action handler subtract from the sleep time until it reaches zero.

Appreciate the suggestion, but i’m not really writing an app.  just looking to understand the idle handler’s capabilities and shortcomings.   i was thinking there might be a handle to the idle handler that would allow me to interact with it.

You don't have access to the timer used with the idle handler, and it is only available when saving as a stay-open application.  Using Cocoa objects such as NSTimer via AppleScriptObjC gives you access to their instances, and most can also be used in a regular script.

I "kinda" used your initial suggestion.  I still used a idle handler, but set the idle interval t0 10 seconds, then put logic into the "on idle" to only execute my desired user action based on a length of time that I can modify via the menu bar.  Gives me what I was looking for.  Thank you for your suggestions.

Though it may not seem obvious — in that D'oh! sort of way — we can invoke the idle handler at any time by using the command idle, just like any other handler. In other words, this code:
on run
    delay 1
    idle
    delay 1
    idle
    delay 1
    idle
end run

on idle
    say "D'oh!"
    return 10
end idle

will call the idle handler every second for three seconds, call the idle handler immediately after exiting the run loop, then call the idle handler every 10 seconds thereafter. We can even pass a variable in, like so:
on run
    delay 1
    idle "D'oh!"
    delay 1
    idle "D'oh!"
    delay 1
    idle "D'oh!"
end run

on idle var
    try
        say var
    on error
        say "Hah!"
    end try
    return 10
end idle

